# Want JS to continue if ID (document.getElementById) isn't found

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a javascript just "ignore" a missing div-id and keep running down the lines. Been searching for solutions, but most of them are either replacing the missing ID or putting information into an already existing one. I just want my script to be "okay" with the fact that certain ID's will not be found.

```
var Info01 = `Some text`;
document.getElementById("Info01").innerHTML = Info01;

var Info02 = `Some other text`;
document.getElementById("Info02").innerHTML = Info02;
```

If the div-id "Info01" isn't present, I want it to just be cool with that and do the next line and so on.

I've been trying some if-statements, but I'm just not good enough to figure it out by myself and google isn't providing me with the solution I'm looking for.

Hopefully someone can help!

Comment: Check if the element with that ID exists first before trying to assign a value to it.

Comment: or use try/catch :p

Comment: `if(document.getElementById('Info01')){ /* it exists */ }`

Comment: it sounds like you are getting an "innerHTML is doesnt exist for undefined" error?

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

Check if the element with that ID exists first.

```
var Info01 = "Some text"; 

if(document.getElementById("Info01")) {
  document.getElementById("Info01").innerHTML = Info01;
}

var Info02 = "Some other text"; 

if(document.getElementById("Info02")) {
  document.getElementById("Info02").innerHTML = Info02;
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit of a stickler for strictness because it helps you understand what is going on.  `getElementById` will return `null` when it can't find the element so the correct (strict) condition is `if (document.getElementById("Info01") === null) {`. You're also missing the `.innerHTML` property in your assignment.

Comment: Thanks @Halcyon, you are right, I did not have time to test.

Comment: @ZacharyMcGee you should just assign the `document.getElementById('Info01')` to a variable in order to not have the javascript have to compute it twice.

Comment: @Fallenreaper you are right also, OP would be best to follow the other answer. I was just attempting to follow their original syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Going a bit further with Zachary McGee's answer. You could avoid some repetition (and fetching twice the id within DOM):

```js
const info01 = "Some text"
const info02 = "Some other text"; 

const setText = (id, content) => {
  const item = document.getElementById(id)
  if (item === null) return
  
  item.innerText = content
}

setText("Info01", info01)
setText("Info02", info02)
```

```html
<div id="Info02"></div>
```

Also not that I am using `.innerText` rather than `.innerHTML`, since the former is sufficient for the needs of your question and the latter [is subject to XSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16860343/6320039).